# Content Template admin interface for custom content type not displaying

Tags: nodes

I'm trying to work with a content template for a custom content type. The admin interface isn't loading... well, it's not fully loading. Here's what I get:

[image: screenshot]

It should, of course, look something like this... which is another custom content type that I created whose content template loads just fine:

[image]

This content type is fairly straightforward. I don't think I've done anything unusual with it... so I'm stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to remove it and create it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was PHP file size limit. Weird. It was increased and everything went back to normal.